# Entity Framework override DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity

Tags: entity-framework

I have a model with `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`, but in a specific situation, would like to save an entity with a specific value for primary key;
ie force `id = 1`

If I just assign the value and save, the id gets overwritten by the auto-generated value.

```
var model = new User {Id = 1};
dbContext.SaveChanges();
Asser.AreEqual(1, model.Id); // false
```

Comment: There isn't anything in Entity Framework that will allow you to use SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON I'm afraid. In your specific situation you could implement a stored procedure to do the work: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn468673.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you can set identity insert on before save change. This is sample.

```
var model = new User {Id = 1};
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[User] ON");
dbContext.SaveChanges();
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[User] OFF");
Asser.AreEqual(1, model.Id);
```

Replace [dbo].[User] with the name of your user table.

Comment: Excited about this option, but I am getting "_Table 'dbo.User' does not have the identity property. Cannot perform set operation._" I am thinking this is because my primary key (Id in the example) is not an int but a Guid. Any thoughts on how to set the Id in the insert when it's a Guid?

Answer (score 0):

I did it via this method:

```
public class User
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public new int Id { get; set; }

    //Rest of the fields...
}
```

You could also make a class that overrides User.

Comment: This does not override SQL Server identity setting.