# Optional DatabaseGenerated property in EF

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have this piece of code and works fine, when I create a new object the database generate new ID

```
   [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public override Guid Id
    {
        get => base.Id;
        set => base.Id = value;
    }
```

My question is: I have one scenario then I need to create a new register using the Model that I use this Id and the Id is fixed, i can't use generated one.
There is any optional parameter to override this generation?

I tried to specify the Id property but EF ignores and generate a new one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15315139/1271037 https://stackoverflow.com/q/31022375/1271037 https://romiller.com/2013/04/30/ef6-switching-identity-onoff-with-a-custom-migration-operation/

Comment: Thanks i will try this ones.

Comment: we always did it in one of two ways: either insert the item within a transaction with IDENTITY_INSERT OR add another parameter to your context constructor that tells your modelbuilder what the DatabaseGemeratedOptions are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to fix using SqlCommand directly, because it's just in database Seed this needs to be called to insert a specific user.

```
        Guid userid = user.Id;
        string email = user.Email;
        string username = user.UserName;
        string avatarurl = user.Details.AvatarUrl;
        string firstname = user.Details.FirstName;

        var sql = @"INSERT INTO
                [Users]
                    ([Id], [Email], [UserName], [EmailConfirmed], [PhoneNumberConfirmed], [AccessFailedCount], [TwoFactorEnabled], [LockoutEnabled])
                VALUES
                    (@Id, @Email, @Username, 'false', 'false', 0, 'false', 'false')";

        SqlParameter[] groupIdParam =
        {
            new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)
            {
                Value = userid
            },
            new SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            {
                Value = email
            },
            new SqlParameter("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            {
                Value = username
            }
        };

        _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, groupIdParam);
```